# Internet explorer 9 not displaying correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I have an issue with my website that is not displaying correctly in IE 9 and below. I have used HTML5shim and that has not corrected the issue.

The site looks great and fine in chrome, firefox etc

My website is www.bucurestideals.com, i was not able to display the HTML code below.

I have my main css code below:

```
body{
    width: 700px; 
    margin: auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* Set styling for ALL h2 elements*/
h2{
    font-size: 39px;
    line-height: 43px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

/*  default anchor styling for the page */
a{
    color: #276056;
    font-size: 14px; 
}

/* Set the hover over of the link */
a:hover {
 color: black;
}

/* Set the base font size and line height for all paragraphs */
p{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}



/* Remove the default padding placed by the browser on the]
   ul element */
.meta {
    padding-left: 0;
    /* Override the default of ul margins */
    margin: 0 0 8px;
}

/*  style the anchor in the UL to have an italic style and 
    a specific font size */
.meta a, .post_info a{
    font-style: italic;
}

/* Style the li of the unordered list to be inline */
.meta li{
    display: inline;

}

/*  Place a '/' after each list item (li) */
.meta li:after{
    content: '\\';
    padding: 0 2px;
    color: #999;
}

/* hide the last '/' in the list item navigation */
.meta li:last-child:after{
    content: none;
}


/* Float the image to the left and add some space 
    between it and the right floated item
*/
article img{
    float: left;
}

/* Style the article's heading - remove default top
 margin top and bottom set by the browser
     */
article h2{ margin: 0; }


/* Float the conrinue link to the right */
.continue{
    float: right;

}

/* Add the brackets around the continue link*/
.continue:after{
    content: ')'
}
.continue:before{
    content: '('
}

/* Float the article div to the right and adjust the width
    so that it will fit to the right of the left floated
    element */
.preview{
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
}
/* style the post information */
.post_info{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #999;
    padding: 3px;
    float: left;
    /* make sure that all text is the same
       size */
    font-size: 14px;
}
/* style the post info  anchor tag */
.post_info a {
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.post_info a:hover {
    color: black;
}


/* Clear any floats declared above it */
.body {
    clear: both;
    /* set text color */
    color: #575757;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "What" isn't displaying correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` (or some other DOCTYPE) to the start of your HTML file.

Comment: This. The page is being displayed in quirks mode by default in IE9.

Comment: Note that if you were using IE10, it would show up something similar to Chrome and Firefox, because IE10's Quirks Mode has finally been updated XD

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use the  tag as the site container, have instead a div to do that work like so.

```
<body>
<div class='site_container'>
//Every other element
</div>
</body>
```

Don't centralize the body element instead centralize the .site_contaner